# Form textbox content with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, textbox

I would like to know  if there is better way to this exercice.
Here it is : Create a form that contain a textbox ;after the user enter the text ,all the letters will be converted to lowercase as soon as he or she clicks elsewhere in the form( hint: use change onChange event handler).

I have written this code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Event</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form>
     Username : <input type="text" id="username"><br>

 <input type="submit" value="button">

 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var  username = document.getElementById("username");

 username.onchange = function(){
 username.value = username.value.toLowerCase();
 };


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Basically i'm replacing the content of the textbox by the formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be too easy, but setting the text over a style to lowercase transform doesn't allow uppercase :)

```js
function toLower(element) {
   if (element && element.value) {
     element.value = element.value.toLowerCase();
     var target = document.getElementById('realvalue');
     target.innerHTML = element.value;
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  onblur="toLower(this)" />

<div id="realvalue"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, whatever is in the input box is still submitted in the same case the user originally typed it when you're only using `text-transform`.  You'll have to use [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) (if you're using PHP) on the receiving end to keep the lower case.

Comment: @ScottKaye You are right, i added an onblur to do it (and added a display function to show it for sure :D)

Comment: Nice!  Of course, if we're being super picky, *that* only works if the user has Javascript enabled ;)

Comment: indeed, but it's a javascript solution that was asked for :D

Comment: your code doesn't allow typing  uppercase letter while  in the box, anyway ,it's a good example of code re-use ,clever and that's cool

Answer (score 1):

But, if all the letters will be converted to lowercase as soon as he or she clicks elsewhere in the form, your code work correctly...
http://jsfiddle.net/b6xwde62/

```
 <form>
     Username : <input type="text" id="username"><br>

 <input type="submit" value="button">

 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var  username = document.getElementById("username");

 username.onchange = function(){
 username.value = username.value.toLowerCase();
 };
 </script>
```

Comment: I know that it works ,i wanted a more clever(or efficient) way to do it.